# Is every element of $Quot(R)$ the root of a monic polynomial in $R[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

In the lecture I encountered the following remark that I do not understand:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $K = Quot(R)$. Now let $a/b \in K$ for $a,b \in R$ with $b \ne 0$. We may assume that $a/b$ is the root of a monic polynomial in $R[X]$.

Why can we assume that $a/b$ is the root of a monic polynomial in $R[X]$? Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: Well, it is a root of $bx-a$, which is not monic unless $b=1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot I now see that I misunderstood the sentence in the lecture. Thanks a lot for your help.